# How can I package a configuration file with a C program?

Tags: c

I am currently trying to build a new version of a piece of software I developed. The software takes a simple command line argument and appends the argument to the end of a file. My problem is that I want to alter the program so:

1. Someone can set up a standard location to save the file to.
2. The program will remember that location.
3. It will still work for anyone installing the C program on mac, linux or windows.

So basically I am trying to figure out how to create a C executable that comes with persistent memory that it can read and modify. Alternatively I would take any way to create an installer to make this easy for anyone who wants to use my program.

If this were a java program I would just add it to the jar file but I have never seen this documented for the C language.

Comment: set the path in an environment variable, then read it from the application

Comment: I agree with set environment variable. Choose a suitable default location too. On Unix, Linux, Mac, think about using either a file `$HOME/.progname` or a directory like that and a file within that directory.  Which is better depends on the purpose and future direction the program might go. For example, if a single user will want the same file content across multiple machines, the file would be OK. If they need different file contents on different machines, use the directory and configure file names based on the machine name.  Provide command line options to specify the file as well.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Environment variables aren't persistent, unless the user goes and edits their bash profile (or the equivalent for whatever shell they're using).

Comment: [Gsettings from Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) provides a good cross-platform persistent settings file collection of tools. You can do the same without it, but where it shines it is already resolves the default user settings storage paths on Linux and Windows. It essentially provided an *ini* like file where you can save any type of data you want in different `[sections]` within the file. It easily handles old/new users with default setting that can be provided until the user modifies one which then remains persistent for that user.

Comment: You can find an example of using the Gsettings tools in [Gtkwrite gtk_appdata.c](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite/blob/master/gtk_appdata.c) which provides both default settings for the application, and then reads the saved keyfile to read in any persistent changes made by the user to the editors settings and finally writes any changes made during its use back to the keyfile before exit.

Answer (score 1):

I would add platform-specific code to store your settings in whatever area users of that particular platform expect. So:

- For Linux: store configuration files in the location specified by `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.
- For Mac: Use [`CFPreferences`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPreferences/Tasks/UsingHighAPI.html)
- For Windows: use the registry

Comment: For Linux there're [XDG recommendations](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), particularly `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (usually, `$HOME/.config/<appname>`).

There's also [Portable Application Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application)